# Python - better way to write this

Tags: python

I have to do this in python so instead of writing these many lines - any other way ?

```
insert into table_a (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_b (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_c (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_d (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_e (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_f (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_g (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_h (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_i (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_j (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_k (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_l (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;

insert into table_m (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;
```

Any code pointers would greatly help to refer.

Comment: SO is not the place for recommendations. Maybe codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Put all the table names in a list. Loop over the list substituting them into the SQL string.

Comment: Although having lots of tables with the same structure is often the sign of a poor database design. Consider refactoring the schema.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it to go until a specific letter, you can just use a string with as many letters as you need and then loop through them. [Thanks to Michael for pointing it out]

```
letters = "abcdefgh"

for letter in letters:
    print(f"insert into table_{letter} (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;")
```

This will return:

```
insert into table_a (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;
insert into table_b (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;
insert into table_c (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;
```

Comment: Strings are iterable in python: `for letter in 'abc':` does the same. And you are using a `list` not a `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the table names in a `list`, then iterate on it and build the query with it

```
tables = ['table_a', 'table_b', 'table_c']
for table in tables:
    query = f"insert into {table} (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from temp;"
```

Comment: Pls lemme know whats the best way to make this happen in Python
I want to call a .sql file which holds may be 10,20 or 50 or 100 or 1000 sqls(CRUD statements) and I want to call the .sql file ONLY from python script, database I am operating is Redshift

Comment: @hellodev https://www.google.com/search?q=python+call+sql+file